# Odoo - How can I get some field's value in purchase module to show in stock module?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

How can I get some field's value in purchase module to show in stock module?

I want to show field (`po_name`) in purchase module in tree view of stock module.

This is my code

```
    <record id="vpicktree_kwan" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">stock.picking.tree.kwan</field>
        <field name="model">stock.picking</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.vpicktree"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <field name="name" position="after">
                    <field name="po_name" string="PO number"/>
                </field>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Could you guide me please?